# Firestore Security rule - Works on SIM but not in code (Missing permission for checking parent document ID)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Firestore setup looks like the following:

```
    match /Profile/{profile}/Sites/{site} {
       allow create : if request.auth.uid == profile;
    }
```

I want the document to be created under the profile of the user only! So I am looking for something like this, but it is not working, I am expecting the profile ID to be populated above.

The following works but then it doesn't check that the site is being created under that user only

```
allow create : if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Profile/$(request.auth.uid));
```

UPDATE: I tried the following condition on the 'create' document in simulator and it works there:

```
Profile/*myUIDHere*/Sites/{site}
```

My security rule which worked on simulator is :

```
match /Profile/{profile}/Sites/{site} {
      allow create : if request.auth.uid == profile;
}
```

But it is not working when I am running the code from the phone - I am getting missing or insufficient permissions error. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('Profile/${currentFirebaseUser.uid}/Sites')
        .document(site.uID)
        .setData(site.toJson())
```

Comment: Does that path exist when you are trying to perform the action?

Comment: @Dharmraj What do you mean? Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: `/Profile/{profile}/Sites/{site}` I meant does this path exists or it is created during the above process?

Comment: I am using it for 'create' permission, so 'site' does not exist but rest of it does.

Comment: Anyone? I still need help in this.